# combining groups in aggregate GROUP BY functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a data table that contains website traffic log information like this

```
date         ip     country     duration
02/12/2013   *      USA           455
02/13/2013   *      CA           1234
02/14/2013   *      Cambodia       13
02/12/2013   *      USA            12
03/11/2013   *      Korea          11
....
```

Now I want to do an sum/group by aggregate query that sums up total visit durations by country, but I want to produce only three groups (USA, Canada, Everyone Else)

And produce an ideal output like this:

```
  country     sum(durations) 
   USA            123456789
   Canada          55555679
Everyone Else        696969
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Comment: My first idea will be to `UNION` 2 queries : 1 for the USA & Canada and 1 for others...

Comment: thats a great idea, but ideally I would like to write it in a single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select country, sum(duration)
from
(
select date, ip, 
       case 
           when country <> 'USA' and country <> 'Canada' then 'Everyone Else'
           else country
       end country,
       duration
from trafficlog
) subsel
group by country
```

Comment: This will give correct results, but the sub-query is unnecessary and makes the query slower than it needs to be. See my answer to this question for an example of how to do this without a sub-query.

Comment: @IkeWalker Thanks for the input. Even though this is a MySQL question, I try to post SQL Ansi answers whenever I can, so if another person has the same issue in other DB, they can try the solution. That said, MySQL accepts aliases in Group by clause, others DBs, not so much.

Comment: I can appreciate that. If I were implementing this on an RDBBMS that doesn't support column aliases in the `GROUP BY`, then I would just repeat the entire `CASE` statement in the `GROUP BY` to avoid sacrificing efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
select (
  case 
    when country in ('USA','Canada') then country 
    else 'Everyone Else' 
   end
) as country_group,
  sum(duration)
from your_table
group by country_group
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT ..
...
GROUP BY
    CASE country
        WHEN 'USA' THEN 'USA'
        WHEN 'Canada' THEN 'Canada'
        ELSE 'Everyone Else'
    END CASE
```

would do the trick. going off the top of my head, so this probably won't work as is. But MySQL does accept arbitrary logic for group/where/order clauses, so you can write whatever you want to do the grouping.

Another option:

```
SELECT IF(country NOT IN ('Canada', 'USA'), 'Everyone Else', country) AS country
...
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: great to know you can put in arbitrary group by logic. will make my life much easier